# How to populate net.Buffers in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to use [net.Buffers](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Buffers) as [follows](https://play.golang.org/p/Wcvduqt-JCW), to read a string into it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    msg := "Hello"
    var bufs net.Buffers
    n, err := bufs.Read([]byte(msg))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("bufs.Read error:", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Read %d bytes", n)
}
```

However, when run `bufs.Read(...)` fails with:

```
bufs.Read error: EOF
```

Contrary to what I thought `bufs.Read(...)` is NOT reading the input argument of this API into itself.

So, how can I fill `bufs` with some data, that can be written to something like a [`net.Conn`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? The argument to `net.Buffers.Read` is a destination slice. You've not written anything to the buffer, and are asking for a 5-byte read -- hence EOF. Even if the read succeeded, the destination slice is unnamed, so couldn't be read.

Comment: I guess you think `Read` reads a string _into_ the buffer, rather than reads a string _out of_ the buffer. `Write` writes a string into the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`net.Buffers.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Buffers.Read) is to implement [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader). Please read the doc what `Read()` means and how it should work.

In short, the `Read()` method is used to read data into the slice you pass to it, data read will be written to that slice.

To read from a `net.Buffers`, first "place" some data into it. `net.Buffers` is a slice of slices:

```
type Buffers [][]byte
```

So simply use the builtin [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) function to append slices to it:

```
var bufs net.Buffers
bufs = append(bufs, []byte("Hello"))
bufs = append(bufs, []byte(" World"))
```

And to read from it:

```
data := make([]byte, 100)
n, err := bufs.Read(data)
if err != nil {
    if err == io.EOF {
        // This just means everything from bufs was read,
        // and data isn't filled completely
    } else {
        fmt.Println("bufs.Read error:", err)
        return
    }
}
fmt.Printf("Read %d bytes\n", n)
fmt.Printf("Data: %s\n", data[:n])
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MCUfCURgKVt)):

```
Read 11 bytes
Data: Hello World
```

Comment: Thanks, what I Was looking for is the `append(...)` call to populate the `net.Buffers`